# 32 bit color in VirtualBox, can't install Mint/Xubuntu/Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, virtualbox, linux-mint

My host OS is Windows 8, I would like to have Mint15/Ubuntu 13.04/Xubuntu 13.04 as guest. I installed Virtualbox 4.3.0 in order to install Mint/Xubuntu/Ubuntu. But I can't even boot LiveCD, here's the error I get when booting Ubuntu through virtualbox:

> "The virtual machine window is optimized to work in 32 bit color mode but the virtual display is currently set to 24 bit.
>
> Please open the display properties of the guest OS and select a 32 bit mode, if it is available, for best possible performance of the virtual video subsystem."

And that's it, I can't go any further, can't even install, boot LiveCD, installer hangs and nothing happening. Any advices?

Comment: Have you checked the "Display settings" like you were told? Right click on os of virtual box and choose `settings` and there is display

Comment: This is not host os related

Comment: This is not of such importance as to make the installation impossible. If you cannot install, it is because something else is preventing it. With this amount of info, this question is a bit too vague to even try to answer.

Comment: do you have a vdi disk on C:\ partition?

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you enable PAE/NX under system>processor. The kernel requires PAE and you should be able to boot and install fine.